# Its about a SQL question asked in an interview

Tags: mysql, sql

In a table there are 201 records. You have to show only the record number 101 when sorted per a set one field or set of fields that define uniquely one record. 
Please, suggest me the right answer and also explain your answer.

Comment: What is the order? Without order 101st row makes no sense as tables are inherently unsorted.

Comment: Explain your question please.  Which database are you using (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server)?  What have you tried already?

Comment: @honeybadger   its done. Try to understand my question . Thanks

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen its done. Try to understand my question . Thanks

Comment: Please include more information. Is it sorted by an `id` ? Or by another column ?

Comment: What is a "sorted table"?  I've never heard of such a thing in any database.

Comment: The question is wrong to begin with. There is no such thing as the 101st row in a table because rows in a table are not sorted. Either you quoted the question incorrectly or the person asking the question does not understand how relational databases work. (Plus: a table contains rows, not records)

Comment: The question probably read _101st row sorted by some criteria_. In which case the answer would be `LIMIT 0, 101`.

Comment: I agree with previous comments that SQL logic considers no order in the tables, so, the "sorted table" concept is wronb. Anyway for the question they did, they refer to the table when shown in screen, so, it is very important that they specify the field that you want to sort as different runs for the same query may obtain different order. If you specify ORDER BY clause with a unique field or combination you will obtain always the same order.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in MySQL but query below should show you exactly what you are required, using the LIMIT:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <YourTable>
ORDER BY <OrderField>
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 100
```

Limit clause has two parts:

```
  LIMIT <row_count> OFFSET <offset>
```

[row_count]: How many lines you want to show

[offset]: How many lines you want to ignore before to show data

Don't forget that need to put the Table name and the Field where you want to order the lines. First, the system will sort and will show the [row_count] by ignoring the quantity mentioned in the [offset]

Answer (score 0):

hi you have to specify the id number  for example

```
SELECT name 
FROM table 
WHERE id=101   -- Assume if you want to find id of 101 from 201 records in a table"
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? What if IDs are not present, or were not assigned ascendingly?

Comment: to be fair, given the lack of information by the OP, this is as good an answer as any.

Answer (score -1):

it does not matter if ids are not assigned or are not in order
It can be achieve using T-SQL function [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

*Numbers the output of a result set. More specifically, returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.*

Comment: What is the relevance to the question?